# Replace images using hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 4 image boxes in one row that are all replaceable on hover. Each image will be different and each image that replaces it with be different.

So far I am using:
.image1 {
    background-image: url("http://vipseogroup.com/amgv2/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/video-production.png");
    height: xx;
    width: yy;
}

.image1:hover {
    background-image: url("http://vipseogroup.com/amgv2/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/so-much-more.png");
}

a

When I attempted to place 4 of these on a row the are aligned in one column not on one row. How do I get them on one row. Thanks

```
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide your current code in either codepen or jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parent element, and assign `display: flex;`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.image1 {
  background-image: url("http://vipseogroup.com/amgv2/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/video-production.png");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.image1:hover {
  background-image: url("http://vipseogroup.com/amgv2/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/so-much-more.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS:

```
div.image1 {float: left }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your divs on one line (in a row)

```
display: inline-block;`
```

or you can do

```
display: flex; 
flex-flow: row; 
flex-direction: row;
```

to your css

Answer (score 0):

I would float them.

```
.image1{
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

OR you could also make the display inline-block

```
.image1{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
```